# Помогите понять в чем ошибочка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу функцию, которая на вход принимает число, а возвращает названия цифр этого числа на английском, например: code_number(201) => 'two zero one'

Вот мой код:

```
description = {1: 'one',
               2: 'two',
               3: 'three',
               4: 'four',
               5: 'five',
               6: 'six',
               7: 'seven',
               8: 'eight',
               9: 'nine',
               0: 'zero'} 

def code_number(num):
    sss = str(num)
    ss = sss.split()
    for x in sss:
        s = description.get(ss)
    return s(ss)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вы неправильно разбили строку на символы, конструкция `split()` делит по разделителю, а вы его не указали.

```py
def code_number(num):
    description = {1: 'one',
                   2: 'two',
                   3: 'three',
                   4: 'four',
                   5: 'five',
                   6: 'six',
                   7: 'seven',
                   8: 'eight',
                   9: 'nine',
                   0: 'zero'}
    stroke = [s for s in str(num)]
    return ' '.join([description[int(letter)] for letter in stroke])
```

Comment: @Helloitisme , хотя этот ответ и даст правильное решение, строка `stroke = [s for s in str(num)]` совершенно бессмысленна - просто подставьте str(num) вместо stroke в следующей строке

Comment: это для наглядности, я конечно мог сделать как вы, записав функцию в 1 строку, но мы же не *** меряемся)). К тому же видно, что человек мало понимает, и будет лучше дать решение, которое он хоть чутка да поймет, чем оно будет работать, но реакция будет - эй, чзнх

Comment: не в том проблема, чтобы чем-то меряться. но зачем один итерируемый объект заменять на другой, итерируемый точно так же. Так что этим кодом вы его научите неправильно

Comment: так то вы правы

Answer (score 1):

```
def code_number(num):
    final = ''
    description = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine', '0':'zero'}
    num = digits_iterative(num)
    for x in num:
        s = description[str(x)]
        final += s + ' '
    return final



def digits_iterative(nonneg):
    digits = []
    while nonneg:
        digits += [nonneg % 10]
        nonneg //= 10
    return digits[::-1] or [0]


print(code_number(2011))
```

Answer (score 1):

join с генератором

```
def code_number(num):
    return ' '.join(description.get(int(s)) for s in str(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
description = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 0: 'zero'}

def code_number(num):
   result = ''
   for i in str(num):
       result += ' ' + description[int(i)]
   return result.strip()

print(code_number(123))
```